# How can i persist only parent object not child object in jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two class A and class B. class A is parent and class B is child
Now I want to persist only A. And I can also update B in future.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "A")
 public class A{
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;
 }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "N")
 public class B{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private A a;
 }
```

when I persist only A then I need to set B object in A. If not set B object in A then get exception. If set B object in A then both object are persist.

Thanks

Comment: What exception do you get and how are you trying to save the objects when you get the exception?

Comment: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: When do you get this exception? From the code you have shown, this can only occur when trying to save an instance of `B` as the association is only defined on `B`. However, in your question you are asking how you can save an `A` without saving a `B` but you are not saving an `A`, you are saving a `B`.

Comment: When I try to save only A

Comment: That is not possible (at least not in the case described in the post). See [this sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43816905) that works fine for the described case. Show us your full code that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

suppose the solution for your question is You need to specifiy the realtionship between `A` and `B`(somthing like `@ManyToOne`).

Or if `A` is not an own Entity, then mark it with `@Embeddable`, and add `@Embedded` to the variable declaration in `B` .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Embeddable
 public class A{
 @Id
 @Column(name="id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private long id;
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "N")
 public class B{


  @Embedded
  private A a;
}
```